Memoir class - I would like to have footnotes without indentation on the first line, but no formatting options seem to work
I am using the memoir class and I am trying to get rid of the space before footnote marks. I would like to have the whole paragraph as a block, without indentation on the first line.
I tried changing the parameters but it doesn't seem to work. The memoir class documentation  (table 12.1, p. 242) indicates values for \footmarkwidth and \footmarksep and the expected results:

1.8em -1.8em Flushleft, regular indented paragraph (the default)
1.8em 0em Indented, block paragraph hung on the mark
0em 0em Flushleft, block paragraph
-1.8em 1.8em Block paragraph, flushleft, mark in the margin
-1sp 0em Block paragraph, flushleft, mark in the margin but flush against the text

I tried the third option but did not see any change. I then tried all possibilities but nothing seems to ever change. Am I defining the lengths not in the right place in the document?
I also tried playing with the footmark box width, without success (and having a footmark in superscript to no avail). To see if anything does anything, I also tried to have ragged right footnotes just to see what would happen… nothing happened. I'm really puzzled.
I don't have any compilation errors (besides the obvious overfull hbox in the text), I have two memoir.cls warnings though: « Generic hook 'package/before/framed' is deprecated. » and « Generic hook 'package/before/float' is deprecated. » I tried to get the latest texlive version in case those were not just warnings, but couldn't make it work on my system and had to revert to the previous install I had. pdflatex --version gets me pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian).
Here would be a MWE:
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[left=22mm,top=32mm,bottom=32mm,headsep=2\baselineskip,textwidth=109.8mm,marginparsep=8.2mm,marginparwidth=55mm,headheight=\baselineskip]{geometry}

%\footnotesinmargin 
\OnehalfSpacing 
\nonzeroparskip

\setlength{\footmarkwidth} {0em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}   {0em}

%changes the parindent in the text, not the footnotes (which was expected)
%\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}

Ces jeunes gens étaient insignifiants ; tout le monde a vu ces figures-là ; quatre échantillons du premier venu ; ni bons ni mauvais, ni savants ni ignorants, ni des génies ni des imbéciles ; beaux de ce charmant avril qu’on appelle vingt ans. C’étaient quatre Oscars quelconques ; car à cette époque les Arthurs n’existaient pas encore. Brûlez pour lui les parfums d’Arabie, s’écriait la romance, Oscar s’avance, Oscar, je vais le voir ! On sortait d’Ossian, l’élégance était scandinave et calédonienne, le genre anglais pur ne devait prévaloir que plus tard, et le premier des Arthurs, Wellington, venait à peine de gagner la bataille de Waterloo.
\footnote{Ces Oscars s’appelaient l’un Félix Tholomyès, de Toulouse ; l’autre Listolier, de Cahors ; l’autre Fameuil, de Limoges ; le dernier Blachevelle, de Montauban.} 
%Indented, block paragraph hung on the mark
\setlength{\footmarkwidth} {1.8em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}   {0em}
\footnote{Naturellement chacun avait sa maîtresse.} 
%trying the box size to see if it works
\footmarkstyle{\makebox[\footparindent][l]{\textsuperscript{#1}}}
%also putting a raggedright that does not do anything
\renewcommand\foottextfont{\footnotesize\raggedright}
\footnote{Blachevelle aimait Favourite, ainsi nommée parce qu’elle était allée en Angleterre ; Listolier adorait Dahlia, qui avait pris pour nom de guerre un nom de fleur ; Fameuil idolâtrait Zéphine, abrégé de Joséphine ; Tholomyès avait Fantine, dite la Blonde à cause de ses beaux cheveux couleur de soleil.}

Favourite, Dahlia, Zéphine et Fantine étaient quatre ravissantes filles, parfumées et radieuses, encore un peu ouvrières, n’ayant pas tout à fait quitté leur aiguille, dérangées par les amourettes, mais ayant sur le visage un reste de la sérénité du travail et dans l’âme cette fleur d’honnêteté qui dans la femme survit à la première chute. Il y avait une des quatre qu’on appelait la jeune, parce qu’elle était la cadette ; et une qu’on appelait la vieille. La vieille avait vingt-trois ans. Pour ne rien celer, les trois premières étaient plus expérimentées, plus insouciantes et plus envolées dans le bruit de la vie que Fantine la Blonde, qui en était à sa première illusion.

\end{document}

I get this result:

(I plan to have the notes in margin in the end and I need all the space I can get there, but the problems are exactly the same.)
I would be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

the french settings interfere and force a specific layout. Use \frenchsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}. Then you will be able to use the memoir commands. (at least that is the case in a current texlive, check the babel-french docu if needed).

This worked! I am so happy! Thank you, I would never have found that on my own. (I don't see arrows to update your answer or I'd do it.)
I added the keyword "french" to my question so that others can find it if they search that way.
